dbplyr cyclic namespace dependency detected: does it unload correctly?
I am unable to unload the tidyverse namespaces after using dbplyr.
Did I find a bug in dbplyr? Does it unload correctly?
library(tidyverse)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars)
DBI::dbDisconnect(con)

unloadNamespace("tidylog")
unloadNamespace("tidyr")
unloadNamespace("purrr")
unloadNamespace("tidyverse")
unloadNamespace("ggplot2")
unloadNamespace("readr")
unloadNamespace("dbplyr")
unloadNamespace("dplyr")
unloadNamespace("tibble")
unloadNamespace("stringr")
unloadNamespace("forcats")
unloadNamespace("magrittr")

library(tidyverse)

results in:
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  cyclic namespace dependency detected when loading ‘dplyr’, already loading ‘dbplyr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘ggplot2’


"detaching and re-attaching a package may not refresh some or all components of the package, and is inadvisable. The most reliable way to completely detach a package is to restart R.", see help(detach)

Note an answer per se, but a simpler version of your example.
The relationship between dplyr and dbplyr is definitely confusing. For example, copy_to() is reexported by dplyr, but other functions (e.g., copy_inline()) are not. Some aspects of dbplyr suggest it's a behind-the-scenes package that users aren't meant to think about, but sometimes users need to call it (e.g., to get window_order() and window_frame()).
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars)
DBI::dbDisconnect(con)

unloadNamespace("dbplyr")
unloadNamespace("dplyr")

library(dplyr)
#> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
#>   cyclic namespace dependency detected when loading 'dplyr', already loading 'dbplyr', 'dplyr'
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Created on 2024-12-29 with reprex v2.1.1
